# what do you call a pie chart with equal arcs but different areas

Tags: data-visualization, pie-chart

I want to create a pie chart for four items, the arc of the slices would be equal, each 90 degrees, however the areas would be different since I will shrink or enlarge the slice depending on the data. Here is an that is close to what I want:

[image: [example](http://www.excelcharts.com/blog/creative-pie-charts-better-infographics/#!wp-prettyPhoto[3934]/0/)]

Basically it would look like a circular bar graph that is filled in the center.
What do you call this type of chart and how would I create it.

Comment: It looks like [polar area diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pie_chart#Polar_area_diagram) (or [rose diagram in geology)](http://www.rockware.com/product/featuresLobby.php?id=165&category=582)

Comment: Like a [coxcomb chart](https://www.google.com/search?q=coxcomb+chart)...

Comment: How you would create it is probably more of a [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) question, but at a minimum, we would need to know what software you would use.

Comment: Personally I think it looks ugly. Is there a good reason to use it?

Comment: According to Wikipedia's article on bar charts, "Statisticians generally regard pie charts as a poor method of displaying information, and they are uncommon in scientific literature. One reason is that it is more difficult for comparisons to be made between the size of items in a chart when area is used instead of length and when different items are shown as different shapes". Additionally, Darrell Huff and Edward Tufte are well known exponents of how to represent data clearly and would be good sources of further reading.

Comment: To quote Tukey "There is no data that can be displayed in a pie chart that cannot be displayed better in some other chart".  You can probably create your chart, but you shouldn't; it is worse than a regular pie chart, and that's saying something.

Comment: @RobertJones, I have a map with different countries and I want some to visualize the number of articles published for each country by four different newspapers. Any suggestions? I only could think of a pie chart.

Comment: you could try a clustered bar chart, if using Excel then I suggest you avoid 3D effects as per Tukey's advice. Depending on numbers, etc you could display the bars horizontally or vertically.  Horizontal bars often work better with longer descriptive labels.

Comment: Right, for a map using pie charts is a common way to display spatial information, included in many GIS programs (unfortunately not roses). (Especially if data are connected to points with certain coordinates, then it is very good to put the centers of pies at this points.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like as a [polar area diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pie_chart#Polar_area_diagram) or [rose diagram](http://www.rockware.com/product/featuresLobby.php?id=165&category=582) (in geology).

To create it, in general, you need to create several circles with radii proportional to your data categories, then just cut slices.

I've plotted these diagrams using Matlab function `rose` http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rose.html

Or try this free program http://www.rgraph.net/examples/rose.html